# Angular $watch not triggering

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

We have one controller and one directive. In the controller's $scope there is `modules` array that contains some objects.

```
$scope.modules = [
   {title: 'demo'},
   {title: 'demo 2'},
   {title: 'demo 3'},
];
```

I am creating directive like this:

```
var popup = angular.element('<module-popup module="module"></module-popup>');
$compile(popup)($scope);
```

Listening to controller's $scope change:

```
$scope.$watch('title', function() {
    console.log('Controller changed');
}, true);
```

When page loads I see in console: `Controller changed`

But when I am trying to change these values manually - in console the are no records BUT at the screen i see correct values.

```
<h2>{{ module.title }}</h2>
```

`$scope.$apply()` throws an error

What am I doing wrong? Thanks

Comment: Probably going to struggle to help without the seeing more of the context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you're watching title but that isn't in your scope, the scope your trying to watch is modules.title or simply modules

```
  $scope.$watch('modules', function() {
        console.log('Controller changed');
    }, true);
```